# Using UIImageView+AFNetworking, images doesn't appear until scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, afnetworking

I'm using `UIImageView+AFNetworking` to load images in table cell, but
images downloaded from server aren't shown in cell until scroll down and up again. I thought that I needed to reload data in `tableView`, but I don't know where to put said reload code.

Here's the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var refresherTool: UIRefreshControl!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let _ = dataRefresher.sharedInstance.refreshVideos(fromUrl: "https://api.vid.me/videos/featured", withLimit: "100", withOffset: "0", completion: {
        featuredVideos in dataRefresher.sharedInstance.featuretVideos = featuredVideos
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })

}

@IBAction func refreshBtn(_ sender: UIRefreshControl) {
    let _ = dataRefresher.sharedInstance.refreshVideos(fromUrl: "https://api.vid.me/videos/featured", withLimit: "100", withOffset: "0", completion: {
        featuredVideos in dataRefresher.sharedInstance.featuretVideos = featuredVideos
        self.refresherTool.endRefreshing()
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
    refresherTool.endRefreshing()
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if dataRefresher.sharedInstance.featuretVideos == nil {
        return 0
    }
    return 100
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "featuredCell", for: indexPath)
    //  if dataRefresher.sharedInstance.featuretVideos == nil { return cell}
    let newImage = UIImageView()
    newImage.setImageWithUrl(URL.init(string: dataRefresher.sharedInstance.getVideosThumbnailUrls(fromVideos: dataRefresher.sharedInstance.featuretVideos)[indexPath.row])!, placeHolderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "first"))
   // newImage.setImageWithUrl(URL.init(string: urls[indexPath.row])!)
    cell.imageView?.image = newImage.image

    cell.textLabel?.text = dataRefresher.sharedInstance.getVideosTitels(fromVideos: dataRefresher.sharedInstance.featuretVideos)[indexPath.row]

    print(indexPath.row)
    print(newImage.image!)
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setImageWithUrl` method is *asynchronous*, meaning that if the referenced image is not in the local cache yet, it will only be downloaded some time in the future.

However, your code tries to get the image out right away:

```
let newImage = UIImageView()
newImage.setImageWithUrl(..., placeHolderImage: ...)
cell.imageView?.image = newImage.image <-- synch call, image is nil here at first!
```

---

Fortunately, there's no need to reload the table view or do any other arcane tricks; just stop doing unnecessary things.

Remove the temporary UIImageView and load the image into the cell's UIImageView directly.

The above code becomes:

```
cell.imageView?.setImageWithUrl(..., placeHolderImage: ...)
```

Comment: Thanks!! It work's! It was not good idea to create temporary variable(

Comment: But I have another problem now, all images shows fine except first 6, they shows when I click on them or scroll down, maybe you know what the problem?